# Angular2/4: Routing with left nav-menu and login page not working

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am creating a new application with login page and for the other pages I have left -nav menu.

I used child routes for the pages and normal route for the login page, everything works fine, but on the right side along with the existing route, previous route page data is also displayed at the bottom of the existing route.

**My app.module.ts**

```
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, 
      children: [
        { path: 'me', component: MeComponent },
        { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent },
      ]  
  },
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>

        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>

        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**login.component.html**

This has the username and password textbox

**me.component.html**

```
<h1>about me <h1>
```

**messages.component.html**

```
<h1> messages <h1>
```

When I go to localhost:4200/home/messages - Messages and about me is also displayed.

Comment: What is `common code` in your home.component.html?

Comment: It is nothing i just kept it as place holder. It can be removed.

Comment: I'd remove everything between the router-outlet tag. What happens if you navigate to `/home/me`?

Comment: Even after removing the common code in between the router-outlet, it is same. when I go to home/me, I see about me and also the login page's username and password textbox. And when I go to home/messages, I see  messages , about me and login page's username and password textbox

Comment: Odd, it sounds like the router is not cleaning up properly. Is there anything else in your code that might be odd and causing this issue?

Comment: Yes it is not cleaning up properly. I posted all the necessary code in the question and I dont think anything else is causing the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159511/discussion-between-llai-and-indra257).